# Software to edit multi channel videos

Tags: gratis, video, video-editing

I'm looking for video editing software that is able to import multiple videos and make edits to all of them at the same time. This will be used to import gaming videos where each video has a different perspective from another player of the same game. The requirements for this software are:

- Windows 7
- Be able to cut videos
- Free of charge (gratis)

Comment: Would a [scriptable editor](https://www.google.nl/search?q=scriptable+video+editor) help you, i.e. you can run the same script repeatedly?

Comment: Possibly, I tried lightworks before and I couldn't get along with it. Could try a few of these though, thank you :)